# Proof of inversion about the mean (Grover's)

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, algorithms

I just have an probably trivial question, but i got stuck when deriving the inversion of the mean as used in Grover's search:
I simply want to show that the application of $(2 \left| \psi \right>\left< \psi \right| - I)$ to an arbitrary state $\sum_k \alpha _k \left| k \right>$ will result in $\sum_k \left[ - \alpha_k + 2 \left< \alpha \right>\right] \left| k \right>$, with $\left| \psi \right>= (1/\sqrt{N}) \sum_{x=0}^{N-1} \left| x \right>$.
I started by simply plugging in the $\left| \psi \right>$ and ending in the following equation:
$$ -\sum_k \alpha_k \left| k \right> + \sum_k \frac{2}{N} \sum\limits_{i,j=0}^{N-1} \alpha_k \left| i \right> \delta_{j,k}$$
What did i mess up exactly? Maybe someone can point out how to get the correct result from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just relabel $j,k\to \ell$ (note that $j=k$ due to the $\delta_{jk}$) and $i\to k$, and you are done, since $\sum_\ell \alpha_\ell=\langle \alpha\rangle$.

Comment: But why is then the sum over all $\left| i \right>$ equal to the sum over all k?

Comment: If you relabel $i$ as $k$, then the sum *is* over all $k$.

Comment: Hmm okay, but then I have to assume that the arbitrary state is also only running over the same range right?

Comment: Yes, this is necessary, and required for Grover's algorithm to work. (Why do you think this might be otherwise?)